# Removing certain number of lines around a specific word

Tags: python

I have a program that is taking info from a website and printing it into a text document, and soon I will format it into a more useable program once back end stuff is done.

The info is in order by time, but all it is is just a string, so it's raw data pretty much. I want it to read line by line and when it hits the key word, it removes the rest of the information. Right now it is just removing the key word, which isn't useful because it leaves a lot of data.

The key word is day, in the list when it becomes days since an update happened it is not useful or useable to include in my info.

```
 PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/new")
try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]'))
    )
except:
    driver.quit()

time = "hours"
txt = main.text
if time in main.text:
    print(main.text)
    print("Newer cryptos found")
else:
    print("No newer cryptos found")
driver.quit()



f = open("CoinMC.txt", "w")
f.write(txt)
f.close()

lines = []
with open("CoinMC.txt", 'r') as fp:
    lines=fp.readlines()

with open("CoinMC.txt", 'w') as fp:
    for number, line in enumerate(lines):
        if number not in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]:
            fp.write(line)

with open("CoinMC.txt", "r") as input:
    with open("CoinMCtemp.txt", "w") as output:
        for line in input:
            if "day" not in line.strip("\n"):
                output.write(line)

os.replace('CoinMCtemp.txt', "CoinMC.txt")
```

I have it removing the first 7 lines because it is not needed. Here is what it prints out

```
 1
OEC SHIB
SHIBK
$0.000007142 1.20% 0.00%
--
$6,259
OKExChain
1 hours ago
2
OEC UNI
UNIK
$24.15 5.97% 0.00%
--
$852,208
OKExChain
1 hours ago
3
OEC FIL
FILK
$59.03 3.55% 0.00%
--
$125,513
OKExChain
1 hours ago
4
Asia Coin
ASIA
$0.1168 0.12% 0.00% $11,679,825 $69,817
Ethereum
1 hours ago
5
BabyDogeX
BDOGEX
$0.000002676 63.03% 0.00% $267,565 $132,537
Binance Coin
1 hours ago
6
Everest Token
EVRT
$0.32 39.45% 0.00% $32,003,854 $127,147
Avalanche
1 hours ago
7
Kurobi
KURO
$0.1113 104.31% 0.00% $44,527,852 $145,578
Solana
1 hours ago
8
Octaplex Network
PLX
$2.73 2.41% 0.00% $2,727 $72,107
Binance Coin
2 hours ago
9
PizzaBucks
PIZZAB
$0.000003016 20.01% 0.00% $603,224 $121,475
Binance Coin
6 hours ago
10
Little Angry Bunny v2
LAB V2
$0 0.00% 0.00%
--
$264,358
Binance Coin
6 hours ago
11
VPEX Exchange
VPX
$0.08024 28.08% 0.00% $76,225,869 $91,560
Binance Coin
7 hours ago
12
Synapse
SYN
$2.05 8.13% 0.00% $111,205,453 $33,736,237
Ethereum
9 hours ago
13
Block Farm
BFC
$2.26 7.46% 0.00% $677,248,899 $1,094,921
Binance Coin
13 hours ago
14
BabySafeMoon
BSFM
$0.01843 13.72% 0.00% $1,842,753 $1,439,599
Binance Coin
18 hours ago
15
Happiness
HPNS
$0.02939 0.08% 0.00% $15,139,185 $64,731
18 hours ago
16
SUCCESS INU
SUCCESS
$0.000000004294 27.82% 50.33% $4,281,116 $1,149,340
Binance Coin
17
GravitX
GRX
$0.1682 47.04% 733.58% $14,761,186 $1,949,928
Binance Coin
18
Prelax
PEA
$0.003075 0.50% 33.13% $1,848,248 $1,566,051
Binance Coin
19
Moonkafe Finance
KAFE
$22.14 0.23% 7.35%
--
$151,714
Moonriver
20
Mini Floki
MINIFLOKI
$0.0000001023 12.92% 21.45% $1,023,333 $969,215
Binance Coin
21
NFTrade
NFTD
$0.5436 4.07% 18.20% $73,387,288 $1,043,752
Binance Coin
22
SafeMoon-AVAX
$SAFEMOONA
$0.000000001448 0.51% 1.50% $1,448,031 $16,582
Avalanche
23
FlyPaper
STICKY
$0.001935 19.19% 102.35% $967,562 $1,020,175
Binance Coin
24
Toll Free Swap
TOLL
$3,936.02 0.48% 8.13%
--
$39,092
Ethereum
25
Fruits Eco
FRTS
$0.7254 0.76% 0.41% $290,176,247 $894,943
Ethereum
26
Decentralized data crypto system
DCS
$4.62 0.31% 3.68% $277,286,959 $1,108,303
Binance Coin
27
Sombra
SMBR
$0.01444 0.80% 13.06% $1,444,036 $92,698
Binance Coin
28
Ether Matrix
ETHMATRIX
$0.0007299 19.49% 80.95% $729,936 $546,747
Binance Coin
29
ForeverFOMO
FOREVERFOMO
$0.0001849 4.18% 683.81%
--
$3,561,670
Binance Coin
30
Mars Panda World
MPT
$0.2678 2.09% 29.60% $23,802,499 $82,606
Binance Coin
```

Pretty much half of the result is just unneeded and adds confusion. You can see how it says 1, then a few lines of info then 2, more info, including the time since it was listed and so on. The first one that was listed a day ago, I want to remove everything below that and possible a number of lines above the key word "day"

EXPECTED RESULT would be

```
 1
OEC SHIB
SHIBK
$0.000007142 1.20% 0.00%
--
$6,259
OKExChain
1 hours ago
2
OEC UNI
UNIK
$24.15 5.97% 0.00%
--
$852,208
OKExChain
1 hours ago
3
OEC FIL
FILK
$59.03 3.55% 0.00%
--
$125,513
OKExChain
1 hours ago
4
Asia Coin
ASIA
$0.1168 0.12% 0.00% $11,679,825 $69,817
Ethereum
1 hours ago
5
BabyDogeX
BDOGEX
$0.000002676 63.03% 0.00% $267,565 $132,537
Binance Coin
1 hours ago
6
Everest Token
EVRT
$0.32 39.45% 0.00% $32,003,854 $127,147
Avalanche
1 hours ago
7
Kurobi
KURO
$0.1113 104.31% 0.00% $44,527,852 $145,578
Solana
1 hours ago
8
Octaplex Network
PLX
$2.73 2.41% 0.00% $2,727 $72,107
Binance Coin
2 hours ago
9
PizzaBucks
PIZZAB
$0.000003016 20.01% 0.00% $603,224 $121,475
Binance Coin
6 hours ago
10
Little Angry Bunny v2
LAB V2
$0 0.00% 0.00%
--
$264,358
Binance Coin
6 hours ago
11
VPEX Exchange
VPX
$0.08024 28.08% 0.00% $76,225,869 $91,560
Binance Coin
7 hours ago
12
Synapse
SYN
$2.05 8.13% 0.00% $111,205,453 $33,736,237
Ethereum
9 hours ago
13
Block Farm
BFC
$2.26 7.46% 0.00% $677,248,899 $1,094,921
Binance Coin
13 hours ago
14
BabySafeMoon
BSFM
$0.01843 13.72% 0.00% $1,842,753 $1,439,599
Binance Coin
18 hours ago
15
Happiness
HPNS
$0.02939 0.08% 0.00% $15,139,185 $64,731
18 hours ago
```

Half would be removed because the program would write/print until it reaches the word "day" then it would stop writing.

Comment: Can you add your expected output. It will be easy to answer then

Comment: Thanks, I added that. I am trying to get better at explaining issues

Answer (score -1):

Important Suggestions for your code:
You can use `range()` function instead of making list:

```
with open("CoinMC.txt", 'w') as fp:
    for number, line in enumerate(lines):
        if number not in range(0, 7):
            fp.write(line)
```

You cannot use keywords like `input` which are reserved by python, which you used here:

```
with open("CoinMC.txt", "r") as input:
    with open("CoinMCtemp.txt", "w") as output:
        for line in input:
            if "day" not in line.strip("\n"):
                output.write(line)
```

Answer to your question:
Try using this:

```
str = "Your Data".split("ago")
del str[-1]
str = "ago".join(str)
```

This will split your string from ago and deletes last item and then rejoin by ago